# What does the syntax df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0:]) do in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

The syntax I am asking is as below:

```
df_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0:])
```

It is found here, why do we need to do it? Why don't we use .columns function?

The syntax is found here:
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/3092/how-to-calculate-correlation-matrix-with-all-colum.html

Comment: it's converting the dataframe to an RDD of tuples

Comment: Why don't we use .columns function?

Comment: why use .columns ? that returns a list of column names, which doesn't include the data

Comment: but sorry for a dump question again, when we load the data using spark.read.csv, isn't the data loaded as a RDD already?

Comment: that returns a dataframe. Please read the docs